# Underscore-case version of ActiveRecord model's name

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, formatting, active-record

Is there a better way to get the underscore-case version of an ActiveRecord model's name? So far this works, but it's far from ideal:

```
my_active_record_instance.class.name.underscore
```

Comment: What do you need the name for? For certain situations, there may be shortcuts. Nothing wrong with your solution though.

Comment: I have several models that have associated files, stored in the public directory like this: `/pdf/#{ model_name }/#{ pubdate }/#{ filename }`. `model_name` is the variable I'm looking for to have one single method for all models. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `singular` method of [ActiveModel::Naming](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Naming.html):

```
ActiveModel::Naming.singular(my_active_record_instance)
```

Alternatively, you can use the `model_name` method that's mixed in to ActiveRecord by the same `ActiveModel::Naming` module. However, it's not available on a record *instance*, so you still have to go through its class:

```
my_active_record_instance.class.model_name.singular
```

or call it directly on the class:

```
MyActiveRecord.model_name.singular
```

The `ActiveModel::Name` instance returned by `model_name` [contains many other inflections and name-related stuff](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Name.html).

You might consider making a module or concern that defines a `name_for_path` (or something) method, and which you can then include in the relevant models, so you can just call that.

By the way, your solution is not uncommon. I looked at the source for the [Paperclip gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip), which constructs file paths from model names, and it does pretty much the same thing to get the model's name, (though I don't know if there's a specific reason for it, or if they too could just as well use the approaches above).

However, if you keep your version, you should probably use `to_s` like Paperclip does:

```
my_active_record_instance.class.to_s.underscore
```